# Why can't we use assignment operator when adding Events dynamically?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I was trying to add dynamic events, but when i use assignment operator only it does not work, but if i use with += operator, it works, could you please help me understand this functionality.

Comment: Because you are *adding* an event handler. You are not setting an event handler.

Comment: what is the difference then Adding an event handler or setting an event handler?

Comment: You can add/subscribe to an event any number of times. You have to make sure that the events are properly removed/unsubscribed when no longer needed (one .NET memory leak cause). The ability to set the handler could cause possible memory leaks and issues if core APIs were reliant on being subscribed to their own events, but got thrown to the side because someone went `=` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you attach a handler to is, in fact, a collection of event handlers. The `+=` for the handler is a semantical equivalent of the `Add` method of the list. The opposite of adding is removing, represented by the `-=` operator. You can read more about it in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms366768.aspx

In case when the property is defined not as event but as `Action<T>`, the property is a container of one function reference. In this case the `=` should be used as the property is not a collection.

Example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var my = new MyClass();
        my.MyAction = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);
        my.MyAction("asdf");

        my.MyEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Event");
        my.InvokeEvent();
    }

    public class MyClass {
        public Action<string> MyAction { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler MyEvent;

        public void InvokeEvent() {
            // the MyEvent can be called only within the MyClass            
            MyEvent(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not just a collection of event handlers, under the hood its a **multicast delegate** see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx A very good explanation though.